# Why Database.SqlQuery is returning 0 rows?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6

I have used this

```
        public List<InspectionReport> GetInspectionReportDetails(int InspectionReportID)
        {
            var List= this.Database.SqlQuery<InspectionReport>("GetInspectionReportDetails", InspectionReportID).ToList();

            return List;
        }
```

in a class that is inherited from `DbContext`

I am calling this function in a controller but List is empty. `Database.SqlQuery` returns 0 items even the procedure is returning data for the parameter i am providing to the function but not this.

Update:

```
alter PROCEDURE GetInspectionReportDetails 

    @InspectionReportID int=0

AS
BEGIN

    Select ir.InspectionReportID
          ,ir.VelosiProjectNo
          ,ir.VelosiReportNo   
          ,ir.Reference
          ,ir.PoNo
          ,ir.InspectionDate
          ,ir.IssueDate
          ,ir.InspectionPhase
          ,ir.InServiceInspection
          ,ir.NewInduction
          ,ir.HydrostaticTest
          ,ir.DimensionalCheck
          ,ir.ThicknessCheck
          ,ir.Patrom
          ,ir.Gvs
          ,ir.FinalOgraInspection
          ,ir.OmcClientRequirement
          ,ir.TankLorryRegistrationNo
          ,ir.TruckTractorManufacturerName
          ,ir.ClientName
          ,ir.Capacity
          ,ir.Omc
          ,ir.EngineNo
          ,ir.TankLorryDimension
          ,ir.ChassisNo
          ,ir.InspectionPlace
          ,ir.TankLorryEnginePower
          ,ir.CarriageName
          ,ir.Brakes
          ,ir.IsSatisfactory
          ,ir.Remarks
          ,ir.Rev
          ,ir.Description
          ,ir.Status
          ,u1.UserName as PeparedBy
          ,u2.UserName as CheckedBy
          ,u3.UserName as ApprovedBy
          ,u4.UserName as IssuedBy
      From InspectionReport ir
      Inner Join dbo.[User] u1
      ON u1.UserID= ir.PeparedBy
      Inner Join dbo.[User] u2
      ON u2.UserID= ir.CheckedBy
      Inner Join dbo.[User] u3
      ON u3.UserID= ir.ApprovedBy
      Inner Join dbo.[User] u4
      ON u4.UserID= ir.IssuedBy

      where ir.InspectionReportID= @InspectionReportID
```

This is the stored procedure that is called by the function.

This the class inpsectionreport;

```
namespace VAILCertificates.DAL.Entities
{
    public class InspectionReport
    {
        //General Details
        public int InspectionReportID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display (Name= "Velosi Project No")]
        public string VelosiProjectNo { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Velosi Report No")]
        public string VelosiReportNo { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Reference { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "PO No")]
        public string PoNo { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Inspection Date")]
        public DateTime InspectionDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Issue Date")]
        public DateTime IssueDate { get; set; }

        //Inspection Phase
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Inspection Phase")]
        public byte InspectionPhase { get; set; } //0= Before, 1= During, 2= Final

        //Types Of Inspection
        [Display(Name = "In Service Inspection")]
        public bool InServiceInspection { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "New Induction")]
        public bool NewInduction { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Hydorstatic Test")]
        public bool HydrostaticTest { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Dimensional Check")]
        public bool DimensionalCheck { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Thickness Check")]
        public bool ThicknessCheck { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "PATROM")]
        public bool Patrom { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "GVS")]
        public bool Gvs { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Final OGRA Inspection")]
        public bool FinalOgraInspection { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "OMC/Client Requirement")]
        public bool OmcClientRequirement { get; set; }

        //Details Of Tank Lorry

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Tank Lorry Registration Number")]
        public string TankLorryRegistrationNo { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Truck Tractor Manufacturer Name")]
        public string TruckTractorManufacturerName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Client Name")]
        public string ClientName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Capacity")]
        public string Capacity { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "OMC")]
        public string Omc { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Engine No")]
        public string EngineNo { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Tank Lorry Dimension")]
        public string TankLorryDimension { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Chassis Number")]
        public string ChassisNo { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Inspection Place")]
        public string InspectionPlace { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Tank Lorry (Engine Power)")]
        public string TankLorryEnginePower { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Carriage Name")]
        public string CarriageName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Brakes { get; set; }

        //ResultsofInspection

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Is Satisfactory?")]
        public bool IsSatisfactory { get; set; }

        //Remarks
        [Required]
        public string Remarks { get; set; }

        //ApprovalSection

        public string Rev { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int PeparedBy { get; set; }

        public int CheckedBy { get; set; }
        public int ApprovedBy { get; set; }

        public int IssuedBy { get; set; }

        //ReportStatus

        public byte Status { get; set; } //0= Prepared 1= CheckedBy 2= ApprovedBy

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for InspectionReport and an example output of the SP ?

Comment: kindly check the updated question

Comment: Where is class `InspectionReport` ?

Comment: udpated, check please

Comment: have you checked?

Comment: `InspectionReport` doesn't match the output of the stored procedure. The user data is returned as string by the sproc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also construct a DbParameter and supply it as a parameter value to your stored procedure:

```
var InspectionReportID= new SqlParameter("@InspectionReportID", 0);

var list = this.Database.SqlQuery<InspectionReport>("EXECUTE dbo.GetInspectionReportDetails @InspectionReportID",InspectionReportID).ToList();
```

It is important to parameterize any user input to protect against a SQL injection attack. You can include parameter placeholders in the SQL query string and then supply parameter values as additional arguments. Any parameter values you supply will automatically be converted to a `DbParameter`.

Comment: in this line: $"EXECUTE dbo.GetInspectionReportDetails @InspectionReportID",InspectionReportID

Comment: @PostingQuestions Edited my answer. Can you try now?

Comment: again error; Must declare the scalar variable "@InspectionReportID".

Comment: In your S.P, declare your parameter as: `@InspectionReportID int` and supply the value from your C#

Comment: @PostingQuestions You are setting it to 0 always in your S.P. Just declare the parameter only.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the the sql statement, I feel the error is how you call the sql statement.

```
var list = this.Database.SqlQuery<InspectionReport>($"EXEC GetInspectionReportDetails {InspectionReportID}").ToList();
```

Comment: ? have u figured out ?

Comment: over this line: ($"EXEC GetInspectionReportDetails {InspectionReportID}")

Comment: Not sure why a compilation error, may be remove the string interpolation and try ("EXEC GetInspectionReportDetails " + InspectionReportID.ToString())

Comment: "Try", "feel"... That's not really an answer. Please either post a comment if you're still in the assuming phase, or use more confident wording when posting an answer. Remember that questions and answers at Stack Overflow will be read by many other users looking for answers.

Comment: This should be composed as: `var list = this.Database.SqlQuery<InspectionReport>($"EXEC GetInspectionReportDetails ({InspectionReportID})").ToList();`

Answer (score -1):

**Try using this code:**

```
public List<InspectionReport> GetInspectionReportDetails(int InspectionReportID)
{
    var List= this.Database.SqlQuery<InspectionReport>("GetInspectionReportDetails @InspectionReportID", InspectionReportID).ToList();
    return List;
}
```

Comment: error; Message = "Must declare the scalar variable \"@InspectionReportID\"."

Comment: Please see my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687235/why-database-sqlquery-is-returning-0-rows#comment98059195_55687569) on the other answer. Also, a short explanation is always appreciated.